# Usar arquivo css externo em JSF

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

dada a minha página de template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Evolutionary</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/estilos.css" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
            <h:form>
                <p:growl id="messages" />

                <p:menubar>

                </p:menubar>
            </h:form>
            <ui:insert name="content">
                    [Template content will be inserted here]
                </ui:insert>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">Versão 1.0</div>
    </div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Dado também uma página qualquer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<ui:composition template="/layout/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="cadastro">
            <p:panel>
                <p:messages />
                <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                    <h:outputLabel value="Nome: " rendered="true" />
                    <p:inputText id="nome" value="#{habilidademb.habilidade.nome}"
                        size="20" />
                    <p:message for="nome" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="Descrição: " rendered="true" />
                    <p:inputTextarea id="descricao"
                        value="#{habilidademb.habilidade.descricao}" rows="6" cols="20" />
                    <p:message for="descricao" />
                    <h:outputLabel id="efeitoS" value="Possui efeito secundário? : " />
                    <p:selectBooleanButton id="efeito"
                        value="#{habilidademb.habilidadeHidden}" onLabel="Sim"
                        offLabel="Não" style="width:60px" />
                    <p:message for="efeito" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="Efeito Secundário: "
                        rendered="#{habilidademb.habilidadeHidden == true}" />
                    <p:inputTextarea id="secundario"
                        value="#{habilidademb.habilidade.efeitoSecundario}" rows="6"
                        cols="20" rendered="#{habilidademb.habilidadeHidden == false}" />
                    <p:message for="secundario" />
                    <p:commandButton action="#{habilidademb.salvar()}" value="Salvar" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

E finalmente o meu arquivo de estilos:

```
body{
    background-color: gray;
}
#efeitoS{
    color: red  ;   
}
```

Para o corpo todo da página consegui usar o estilo. Não estou conseguindo usar para os elementos que estão dentro meu content (Parte editável da página). Alguém sabe como resolvo isso?

Comment: Bom, Sugiro algumas alterações, na sua página inicial, declare o css assim: <h:outputStylesheet library="pastadoseucss" name="estilo.css" />, nos componentes do primefaces chame a classe através da propriedade styleClass="classecss", e escreva suas classes css assim .{codigo css ...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estou usando um CSS com o mesmo nome que o seu, para fazer ele funcionar, declarei ele da seguinte forma:

```html
  <h:outputStylesheet name="estilo.css" library="css" />
```

Dê uma olha na estrutura de pastas que usei na imagem abaixo. Como Douglas disse. sempre utilize styleClass, quando possível.

[image: Minha estrutura de pastas no NetBeans]